# Using IN operator on list by using Rowfilter i am getting an error “The expression contains invalid name: '[])'.”

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a multi-select drop-down list, and I am saving these selected values in a list and then comparing list items by using the IN operator, but I am getting an error:The expression contains invalid name: '[])'

```
List<string> Transpoters = new List<string>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (ListItem item in TransporterDropDownList1.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)

        Transpoters.Add("'" + item.Value + "'");
}

ReportViewer.Reset();
DateTime fDate = DateTime.Parse(datetimepicker1.Value);
DataTable dt = GetDate(DateTime.Parse(datetimepicker1.Value), DateTime.Parse(datetimepicker2.Value));
if (MillDropDownList2.SelectedIndex > -1 && TransporterDropDownList1.SelectedIndex > -1 && Contract_Number.Value.Trim() == "")
{
    DataView Dv = new DataView(dt);
    Dv.RowFilter = "Mill_Name= '" + MillDropDownList2.SelectedValue + "' AND Transporter_Name IN  (" + string.Join(",", Transpoters.ToArray() + ")");
    DataTable filter = new DataTable();
    filter = Dv.ToTable();
    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", filter);
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"RPT/MolassesLifting.rdlc";
    ReportParameter[] rptParams = new ReportParameter[]
        {
        new ReportParameter("FromDate",datetimepicker1.Value),
        new ReportParameter("Todate",datetimepicker2.Value)
        };
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParams);
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your closing parenthesis of Join are in the wrong place. :

```
Dv.RowFilter = "Mill_Name= '" + 
    MillDropDownList2.SelectedValue + 
    "' AND Transporter_Name IN  (" +
    string.Join(",", Transpoters.ToArray()) + 
    ")";
```

Comment: @Mangnetron  thanks it solve the error but I didn't get sorted list on the base of this dropdown selection.Can you please help me?

Comment: @Scarface1122 you should probably ask another question, as this is a different issue. What you're trying to do? Sort the DataView? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.sort?view=netframework-4.8